# Runtime Error 1004 when replacing formula

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the following code to add something to a Formula in VBA (for debugging purposes I am using the variable currentFormula, instead of doing it directly):

```
currentFormula = Range("A" & row).Formula
currentFormula = currentFormula & "+" & CStr(difference)
Range("A" & row).Formula = currentFormula
```

When going through the code step by step, the variable currentFormula has the correct value before the final step, e.g. "=A1/A2+0.5". However, then the script Fails with runtime error 1004. When I am Setting currentFormula manually to something like "=10+10", the script works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CStr` formats the number according to the current system locale.
`Formula` accepts formulas in English.

The function that converts numbers to strings in an invariant way is `Str`. Note that it prepends a space to positive numbers which you might want to remove:

```
currentFormula = currentFormula & "+" & LTrim$(Str$(difference))
```