# Excel VBA use operators <,>, >=, <= with doubles as function arguments

Tags: excel, vba, arguments, double

I posted a question a few minutes ago about this matter and decided to create a new one with the problem a little better described. So I prepared a simple worksheet:

[image: sheet example]

On `G4` (green) I placed the formula `=SUMIFS(B1:B20;A1:A20;">="&E4;A1:A20;"<"&E5)` and it works fine.

The cell `E4` (blue) is filled by the script:

```
Sub Button1_Click()

    Dim SH As Worksheet: Set SH = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim R1 As Range: Set R1 = SH.Range(SH.Cells(1, 1), SH.Cells(20, 1))
    Dim R2 As Range: Set R2 = SH.Range(SH.Cells(1, 2), SH.Cells(20, 2))

    Dim V1 As Double: V1 = SH.Cells(4, 5).Value
    Dim V2 As Double: V2 = SH.Cells(5, 5).Value

    SH.Cells(5, 7).FormulaR1C1 = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(R2, R1, ">=" & V1, R1, "<" & V2)

End Sub
```

It's easy to see that the value should be also `18`. However it evaluates to `0`.

Another thing, when I declare `V1` and `V2` as longs:

```
    Dim V1 As Long: V1 = Int(SH.Cells(4, 5).Value)
    Dim V2 As Long: V2 = Int(SH.Cells(5, 5).Value)
```

the cell `E4` (blue) evaluates to `17` (which is correct because there's `17` values between `44004` and `44005`).

Does anyone know something about this? It looks like a bug to me...

Comment: It's never "a bug"

Comment: @braX, it would be more accurate if you had write "It's never ""a bug"""

Comment: It is sometimes a bug though, but not in this case. You are not setting a formula, even though you are using `.FormulaR1C1`, you are storing the resulting value (for which it's appropriate to use `.Value` but `.FormulaR1C1` lets you get away with it). From the screenshot the decimal dot in your locale is `,`. The values passed to `SumIfs` should be formatted with `.`.

Comment: I'm going to say something really stupid but who knows? When you declare `V1` and `V2` as Long, it becomes an integer, and the criteria expression `>=44004` makes sense to Excel. When you declare it as Double, it admits decimals but in VBA. The decimal separator in VBA is the dot, not the coma like in your Excel settings in your image. So the criteria expression becomes `>=44004.12497` makes no sense to Excel. And yes, this comment is a total shot in the dark, but looking what you posted, I do not see anything else.

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns It's the other way round. Because the locale's decimal dot is `,`, the implicit `CStr(V1)` formats it with a `,`, and the VBA engine requires the `.`.

Comment: @GSerg, you're wrong. Whatever you use `.FormulaR1C1` or `.Value`, is exactly the same case here. I already tried it.

Comment: @Pspl I'm not saying that your misuse of `.FormulaR1C1` is the source of the problem. I simply mentioned it because it makes the code appear to be what it's not, but your problem is about the decimal dot.

Comment: Given your comment reply to @braX about the use of double quotes, missing the comma and decimal point is a bit of an "own goal"...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your screenshot, your decimal dot is the `,`.

When you concatenate a string with a number, such as in `">=" & V1`, the number is converted to string using the current locale. Your current locale has `,` as the decimal dot, so you end up with `">=44004,2"`.

Internally Excel stores all formulas according to the en-us locale, which, among other things, uses `.` for the decimal dot. These are accessible via `.Formula` and `.FormulaR1C1` properties.
The Excel interface shows you these formulas converted to your locale. These are accessible via `.FormulaLocal` and `.FormulaR1C1Local` properties.

The functions under `WorksheetFunction` only expect the true internal en-us arguments. When you pass `">=44004,2"` as an argument, it causes the calculation to fail, because the function expected `">=44004.2"`. The zero result is [an indication](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sumifs-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b#tblID0EAAFAAA) that a filter was malformed.

So you should [give it that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51191954/11683):

```vb
= WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(R2, R1, ">=" & Str$(V1), R1, "<" & Str$(V2))
```

Comment: Can I give you 100 Thumbs Up?

Comment: So my comment was not totally absurd. I'm so happy reading your answer, even If my toughts where the opposite, but it was kind of in the good way. Thumbs up